# windows() closing when R terminates

Tags: r

I wonder if there is a workaround for how to keep output from windows() open after R terminates.

To specify. I've built a system  for production which is run from BASH. BASH runs the R instance and terminates it when it is finished. During the run it produces plots which i would like to display and keep open even after the R instance terminates so I can decide to keep them or not.

Can you keep the opened windows from closing or is there an alternative?

Don't really know what the example code would be here... since all im using is grDevices::windows().

Any suggestions?

```
  # Plot data for overview ----
     if(cfg$verbose) cat(crayon::green("Plot data for visualization of 
                                        problem\n"))
        plots <- Learning_package::plot_iris(dat)
        grDevices::windows();gridExtra::grid.arrange(plots$p1, plots$p2, 
                                                     plots$p3, plots$p4, 
                                                     plots$p5, plots$p6, 
                                                     nrow = 2)
```

Expected result is to NOT close the window when bash is finished with its run.

Comment: Write the plots to an image or PDF and open the image in a system image or PDF viewing application? What do you mean by "decide to keep them or not"? Keep them how?

Comment: I can do that, but I would like to view them before I save them or toss them. But maybe always saving is the easy solution...

Comment: If R has closed, then R's graphics windows are dead, you can't see them or do anything. How do you want to save the plots? If you launch a PDF viewer you can use a "Save" option in that to save the PDF. Somehow you are going to have to start another separate process if you really need R to quit.